# using const_cast on constant data type

Tags: c++, const-cast

As much as I know, const_cast may be used to cast away (remove) constness or volatility. But I could not understand the execution of the code below.

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
     const int i = 20;
     int *p = const_cast<int*>(&i);
     std::cout << "i:" << i << "   *p:" << *p << "   p:" << p << "   &i:" << &i << std::endl;

     (*p)++;
     std::cout << "i:" << i << "   *p:" << *p << "   p:" << p << "   &i:" << &i << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

When I tried to run the above code, following result was obtained:

```
i:20   *p:20   p:0x7ffc579d18e4   &i:0x7ffc579d18e4
i:20   *p:21   p:0x7ffc579d18e4   &i:0x7ffc579d18e4
```

Can anyone explain me the output. I am new to C++ and trying to understand different casting operation. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not be confused by the fact the cast in the dupe occurs in another function. It's exactly the same question save for that.

Comment: Yes, `const_cast` can be used to remove `const` but if you violate the `const` contract and modify something that was declared `const` then you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Using `const_cast` to remove `const` from something that was declared `const` and then access it in a non-const way is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Just because you can do something, and the compiler does not complain, does *not* make it valid.

Comment: Correction: _"`const_cast` may be used to cast away (**pretend to** remove) constness or volatility"_

Comment: @JesperJuhlI am not talking about it's valid or not valid. All I want to know how is it even possible for the same memory location to show two different value. whats really happening over here? 
for example, when I pass a reference(which is a constant) to a thread, I know that variable is a reference to the temporary value copied at the new thread’s stack( it has a different memory location) but that's not the case here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so if it just pretends to remove constness, then what is the purpose of having it?

Comment: @Sourav: Not much. Some hacks when you are forced to deal with C APIs that "implement" `const` only by documentation.